# User defined language in pandoc code-block

Tags: markdown, coq, pandoc

I'm trying to write a code-block in `Coq` (long story :)) inside `pandoc`.

```
$ pandoc --list-highlight-languages | grep coq | wc -l
0
```

Since it doesn't exist, I wonder if there is an option to write *my own user-defined* code-block-language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends a little on the output format that's being targeted. The most general solution is to define a syntax definition. Pandoc can parse XML syntax definitions for the Kate editor, see https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/highlight.html for more info on the format. If you have such an XML file, then pass it to pandoc via the `--syntax-definition` command line option.

If the output format is LaTeX (or PDF via LaTeX), then using pandoc with the `--listing` option should work, esp. when combined with the tips mentioned here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434523/

Likewise, *minted* can be used for highlighting, see the [minted.lua](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/minted) filter.

Last but not least, using an external syntax highlighter would be possible via a filter. [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) are well suited for that task, as they do not require an additional tool-chain to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

The `pandoc` executable can be extended with custom filters: https://pandoc.org/filters.html

---

And for transforming `Pandoc` documents directly in Haskell (without going through filters), a useful thing is the traversal [`Text.Pandoc.Walk.walkM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.22.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Walk.html#v:walkM) and other related functions in `pandoc-types`.

For example I've used that in [`hakyll-alectryon`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-alectryon) to process Coq code blocks using pandoc, in Hakyll.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness reasons, I am pasting a minimal `xml` syntax file for an *html slideshow* generated from a *markdown file* with *pandoc*. It is made as a skeleton for anyone writing a [dsl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and wants to easily mark specific words in a code block. See [here](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/tree/master/data/syntax) many full syntax examples

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language name="coq" extensions="*.v" indenter="haskell">
  <highlighting>
  <list name="kw_major">
    <item>induction</item>
    <item>Fixpoint</item>
    <item>Theorem</item>
    <item>Qed</item>
  </list>
  <list name="kw_minor">
    <item>exists</item>
    <item>forall</item>
    <item>nat</item>
  </list>
  <contexts>
    <context name="Normal" attribute="Normal" lineEndContext="#stay">
      <keyword    attribute="KwMajor" context="#stay" String="kw_major" />
      <keyword    attribute="KwMinor" context="#stay" String="kw_minor" />
      <Int        attribute="Decimal" context="#stay" />
      <DetectChar attribute="String"  context="String" char="&quot;" />
    </context>
    <context name="String" attribute="String" lineEndContext="StringSyntaxError" >
      <DetectChar attribute="String" context="#pop"  char="&quot;"       />
      <RegExpr    attribute="String" context="#stay" String="[^&quot;]*" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
  <itemDatas>
    <itemData name="KwMajor" defStyleNum="dsDataType"/>
    <itemData name="KwMinor" defStyleNum="dsKeyword"/>
    <itemData name="Decimal" defStyleNum="dsDecVal"/>
    <itemData name="String"  defStyleNum="dsString"/>
  </itemDatas>
  </highlighting>
  <general><keywords casesensitive="1" /></general>
</language>
```